# How to load Tensorflow 1.x saved model in TensorFlow 2.x using C++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

The python interface for Tensorflow v2 has *tf.compat.v1.GraphDef* and *tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader* for dealing with old models. I used previous C++ code to load a v1.x model in TF v2.x with no success (Error text: "PruneForTargets: Some target nodes not found"). The code is as follows:

```
    tensorflow::Session* session;
    tensorflow::SessionOptions options;
    TF_CHECK_OK(tensorflow::NewSession(options, &session));

    // Read in the protobuf graph (e.g. model.pb)
    GraphDef graph_def;
    Status status = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), graph_fn, &graph_def);
    if (status != Status::OK()) return status;

    // create the graph
    status = session->Create(graph_def);
    if (status != Status::OK()) return status;
```

However, I did not find anything on *compat* or whatsoever in google TF docs for C++.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btensorflow%5D+v1+v2 -- have you checked these? In any case, please provide a [mcve] with code and data and include the full output it produces.

Comment: Yes, I did. In fact, you should've checked [tensorflow c++ v1 v2](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btensorflow%5D+v1+v2+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D) because my question concerns C++. The python interface can do the job.